# Extract an ext2 filesystem image in a Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to extract an ext2 initrd filesystem image as part of a Dockerfile build.

I have tried these approaches so far:

- Mounting as a loopback device. This can't be done due to permissions. It seems like you can override this with --privileged, but this can only be done for 'docker run', not 'docker build'.
- libguestfs. I couldn't get this to work, and it required a huge Fedora image to run it.
- Extracting using 7z. Unfortunately this does not preserve permissions and symlinks are converted in to regular files. I can't find any options that would preserve them.

I'm almost at the point of trying to boot the initrd using QEMU, creating a rootfs tarball and copying it out using the virtual network, but surely there's an easier way. I'm surprised there are no userland tools to easily extract a filesystem image.

I could manually prepare a tarball using the loopback method, but the point of using Docker is to automate this.

Comment: No, I didn't think there was a FUSE implementation of ext filesystem. Is there?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2, but it looks like I will have to compile it myself as there are no packages for Linux.

Comment: I managed to get it to compile, but it gives the error: fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first, and 'modprobe fuse' doesn't work either